# Unable to use macro for \end{<environment name>} for environment defined using \NewEnviron

Tags: environments

I would like to use a shorthand to begin and end an environment, such as `\be` and `\ee`. This works as expected for standard environments, such as `equation` as illustrated below.

```
% this compiles fine
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\be}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}
\be y = ax + c \ee
\end{document}
```

However, using an environment defined using `\NewEnviron` as shown below does not compile.

```
% this does not compile: ! LaTeX Error: \begin{someenv} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{someenv}{someenv: \BODY}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{someenv}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\end{someenv}}

\begin{document}
\be y = ax + c \ee
\end{document}
```

Using `\end{someenv}` explicitly compiles fine again.

```
% this compiles fine
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{someenv}{someenv: \BODY}
\newcommand{\be}{\begin{someenv}}
% \newcommand{\ee}{\end{someenv}}

\begin{document}
\be y = ax + c \end{someenv}
\end{document}
```

Do you know why using `\ee` does not compile and how I might be able to fix this issue?

Comment: Don't do this, just don't. Learn to use your editor properly instead. The full environments makes the code much more readable.

Comment: environments that grab their body as argument need to find the end by looking for the exact string marker. You can't hide them. And like daleif I think that you shouldn't use such shortcuts. E.g. your editor can do better highlighting if you use the normal syntax.

Comment: Understood regarding using normal comments for better readability. I should've provided more context on the specific use case: I would like to redefine `\(` and `\)` to temporarily hide equations for a word count. `texcount` doesn't quite do the job because references need to be included in the word count.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** You can’t.

The contents of `someenv` has to be grabbed by looking for *explicit* `\end{someenv}`.

If you want to obfuscate your code, do

```
\long\def\be#1\ee{someenv: #1}
```

but then don’t ask how to use something else instead of `\ee`, because the problem is the same.